# How do I set up a Google Calendar for my group?

Tags: google-plus, google-calendar

I belong to a group that puts on events. Different people organize different events, but we are all under the umbrella of one group name. We want to create a Google Calendar where we can all add events to it.

We first created a Google account, and shared the login information, and then started putting events on it. However, when we exported the calendar, we found that it showed up in other people's calendars under the name we use for the Google account, not the name of our group. We tried changing the name of the account to reflect the group name, but got a warning saying we were violating Google's naming policies.

The same warning said that if we wanted to create a calendar for a group, we should make a Google+ page, which I did, but I can't see any way of creating a calendar with it.

How do we get a calendar that is for our group, displays under our group name when people import it, and all our members can add events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key is that you need to create a Google login for your G+ page.

If you go to the "Settings" section for your G+ page, you should find a section called "Third Party Tools" and what looks like an email address. Set up a password for that, and you should be able to then log in to Google with those credentials and add things to a Google Calendar.

Comment: [Set up a password for your Google+ page - Google My Business Help](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4570250?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

1. Set the account's main calendar name properly.
2. Use a Google Group to manage Google Calendar sharing and collaboration.

## Explanation

### Part 1: Set the account's main calendar name properly

The main calendar for a Google account takes it's default name from the account name, but it could be changed. To do so,

> 1. On your computer, open Google Calendar.
> 2. On the left side of the page, click My calendars.
> 3. To the right of your calendar, click the dropdown menu  > Calendar settings.
> 4. In the box at the top, choose a new name.
> 5. At the bottom of the page, click Save.

### Part 2: Use a Google Group

Any Google account could be used to create calendars with Google Calendar. While using a Google+ page login could be possible, for managing and adding events by a large number of members it's very helpful to use a Google Group, because this helps both to manage group membership and to avoid the risk that the account be blocked.

> ### Share with a Group
>
> #### Use Google Groups
>
> If you want to share a calendar with a large group of people, you can
> add a Google Group. The calendar sharing settings will automatically
> adjust to any changes in the group's membership over time. Learn more
> about [Google Groups](https://support.google.com/groups/topic/9216).

## Remarks

- If you share the login information of a Google account, do this for backup/absence substitution purposes. Using a Google account for daily activities by several users could make that Google consider the activity as suspicious and block the account.

## References

- [Create a new calendar - Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37095?hl=en)
- [Share your calendar with someone - Calendar Help](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en)
- [Set up a password for your Google+ page - Google My Business Help](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4570250?hl=en)